# Ajax request giving duplicate data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

actually I am inventing a newsfeed script for my own purposes and I am getting some duplicate error anyone any help would be appreciated. Here is the explanation for the question:
I call last 5 posts from the database from a file called feed into my page using ajax when the window loads and after 100 milliseconds another function that gets the next 2 is executed and the attribute of the last Child id of the div in which the first request sends data is sended with it and a sql statement is run if the post parameter is specified and the results are coming but they are duplicate please help. The data is selected from the database (second time) which is lesser than the POST parameter last_time which is sended to the file.

Here is the code html:

```
<div id="newsfeed">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
    setTimeout(feed, 100);
function feed(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
           $("#newsfeed").append(xmlhttp.responseText);
       }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","processors/feed.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    setTimeout(feed_update, 1000);
}
function feed_update(){
    var xmlhttp;
    var last_time = document.getElementById("newsfeed").lastChild.id;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
           $("#newsfeed").append(xmlhttp.responseText);
       }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","processors/feed.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("last_time="+last_time);
}
```

And here is the php code of the feed.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['last_time']) == true):
       $posts_data = "SELECT
                            *
                         FROM
                            posts
                        WHERE
                            post_by='".$friends['id']."'
                          OR
                            post_by='Advertisement'
                          AND
                            (privacy !='only_me' OR ad_if_last_date >= '".$today."')
                          AND
                            date < '".$_POST['last_time']."'
                        LIMIT
                            1";
    else :
        $posts_data = "SELECT
                            *
                         FROM
                            posts
                        WHERE
                            post_by='".$friends['id']."'
                          OR
                            post_by='Advertisement'
                          AND
                            (privacy !='only_me' OR ad_if_last_date >= '".$today."')
                        LIMIT
                            1";
     endif;
        $news_feed = array();
        $posts_result= mysqli_query($conn,$posts_data);
        while($posts= mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts_result)){
              $news_feed[] = $posts;
        }
        foreach ($news_feed as $news_feed_item): ?>
           <ul class="post" id="<?php echo $news_feed_item['date']; ?>">
```

Actually there are more code that I have omited for security reasons this will give you a idea to work on with please help please....

Please help

Comment: since you are using jQuery why not use `$.ajax` API to streamline ajax code?

Comment: `last_time` is the `id` of the previous post and not the date? your code seems misleading, could you provide the values set in those variables...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is it I got the answer thanks to all I myself learned it
Here is the code in case you all need it:

```
    $current_time = $_POST['last_time'];
    $item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts_data);
    $last_news_time = $item['date'];
    while ($last_news_time < $current_time) {
        usleep(1000); //giving some rest to CPU
        $resource = mysqli_query($posts_data);
        $item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts_data);
        $last_news_time = $item['date'];
        if(!$item['date']){
            $last_news_time = -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm concerned about the architecture of your application, first of all `feed()` and `feed_update` do exactly the same thing, apart from `feed()` makes a call to `feed_update()` a second later.

My second point, which is related to why you are getting repeat data is the way you transact with your database, why on earth would you want to open a connection, retrieve 1 result and then reconnect and pull back a new result each second - this is an extremely network expensive way of requesting resources.

A better way to do this, would be to pull back a collection of post (maybe a limit of 25), and then every minute or two send another call to retrieve the next 25 results, this way you won't return duplicate post data.

You could achieve this by setting a constant of `requestAmount = 25` and have another var to hold the current amount of posts `totalPosts = 0`.

This would then work like this as the script was called each minute:

```
page load = 0 posts
run feed_update = 25 posts
1 min later     = 50 posts (25 + 25)
1 min later     = 75 posts (50 + 25)
```

You could also update the feed when a user presses a fetch button - these are just some suggestions for you, but you really need to make some changes!

Comment: I actually want to select the posts which are lesser than the last post appeared I wont call it ever 100 milliseconds I AM NOT A FOOL TO DO SO Its just demonstarting can you give me my problem is that it gives the same post over time again and again

Comment: Apologies for the scrutiny then - I see people making expensive calls a lot so wanted to point it out - could you update your question so other SO users who may give an answer are clear of how you plan to make requests

Comment: And one more thing can you provide the answer

Comment: I pointed out some other discrepancies with your code `last_time` is misleading, is that a DATE or the ID of the last post?   Could you provide a dump of your query for the case where you have `date < x` as I believe this is not getting ran.